# mysql test IF variable IS NULL (or empty)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

we are selecting a row in mysql/mariadb and storing chosen columns in variables. After this, using `IF` we would like to test one of the variables and see if it has been set or is null, if it is then we assign it a value and continue on.

Using `IS NULL` does not seem to work on a non expression.

```
select id,history,active,jsonorder
INTO @id,@history,@active,@jsonorder
from myTable where uid = myUid
delimiter |
IF @jsonorder IS NULL THEN
  @myNewVal="zzz";
ELSE
  @myNewVal="yyy";
END IF|
insert into otherTable (colA) VALUES (@myNewVar);
```

What is the correct way to test if the `select` has provided a value into a variable such as `@jsonorder`?

Comment: what you mean doesnt seem to work? are you working inside a function?

Comment: be carefull because `ORDER` is a reserved word

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, clarified order to jsonorder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use an expression in the SELECT list:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.history
     , t.active
     , IFNULL(t.order,1) AS `order`
  INTO @id
     , @history
     , @active
     , @order
  FROM `myTable` t
 WHERE t.uid = ...
```

---

Note that `DELIMITER` is not a SQL statement; it's command recognized by the mysql command line client (and some other clients).

documented here in MySQL Reference Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-commands.html

---

It's not clear in what context this script is being run; is this part of a MySQL stored program, or being called application code. What we are actually trying to achieve?

---

There are several other expressions we could use in the SELECT list, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN t.order IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE t.order END`
```

or

```
IF(t.order IS NULL,1,t.order)
```

et al.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

If we don't want to modify the original SQL statement; if we execute this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.history
     , t.active
     , t.jsonorder
  INTO @id
     , @history
     , @active
     , @jsonorder
  FROM `myTable` t
 WHERE t.uid = ...
```

And then we want to perform an assignment to another user defined variable, based on a conditional test, we can achieve that in another `SELECT` or a `SET` statement.

For example:

```
SELECT @myNewVal := IF(@jsonorder IS NULL,'zzz','yyy') ;
                      ELSE 'yyy'
```

-or-

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN @jsonorder IS NULL 
         THEN 'zzz'
         ELSE 'yyy'
       END
  INTO @myNewVal
```

-or-

```
SET @myNewVal := IF(@jsonorder IS NULL,'zzz','yyy')
```

Comment: I have updated the sql query to reflect a post `IF` insert action on a different table and a different variable. This statement is read by php and or bash scripts to be run.

Answer (score 1):

The `IF` *statement* can only be used in Stored Routines.  The `IF` *function* can be used virtually anywhere an expression can be put:

```
select id,history,active,jsonorder
    INTO @id,@history,@active,@jsonorder
    from myTable
    where uid = myUid;
insert into otherTable (colA)
    VALUES (IF(@jsonorder IS NULL, "zzz", "yyy"));
```

Where does `myUid` come from?

Is `otherTable` only one column wide?  Or do all the other columns have defaults?

(I'm worried that you over-sanitized the question.)

Answer (score 0):

This solve for cases where order is null, but not for when myUid doesnt exist in your table

```
SELECT id,history,active, COALESCE(order,1)
INTO @id,@history,@active,@order
FROM myTable 
WHERE uid = myUid
```